# What is the optimal connection pool max for Heroku Postgres' 'Standard-0' database?

Tags: heroku, database-connection, connection-pooling, heroku-postgres

I'm just configuring a system for production and we have chosen Heroku's Postgres Standard-0 as the database.  This states the maximum connections is 120 but I am aware that this does not mean I can set Sequelize's `POOL_MAX` to 120 as there are other considerations.

From experience, what would be an upper `POOL_MAX` setting?

Comment: How many clients will be connection? For instance, how many dynos will connect to this database? Are there additional clients that will connect aside from the application (thinking BI or ETL tools)?

Comment: Just the one dyno, and in general no external access

Answer (score 0):

Since Heroku needs to occasionally connect to your database to perform health-checks and various other tasks, I wouldn't recommend setting `POOL_MAX` to 120 as you've already intuited. A figure around 110 seems more appropriate as it will leave room for Heroku to monitor the database and allow a couple extra connections in case you need to connect to the database in a pinch. If you add more dynos or have other clients connecting to the database regularly, you'll want to adjust the `POOL_MAX` setting downward to account for the additional connections.

Comment: Are you missing a value between 'around' and 'seems'?

Comment: I certainly was. Edited it to clarify.